# push_back for vector in struct not working

Tags: c++, struct, stl

Here is the code I am trying to compile:

```
int main(){
    struct node{
        pair<int, float>* neighbors;
    };
    pair<int, float> wvertex;
    int VCount, v1, v2;
    float w;
    cin >> VCount;
    node* graph_nodes[VCount+1];
    while( cin >> v1 ){
        cin >> v2 >> w;
        wvertex.first = v2;
        wvertex.second = w;
        graph_nodes[v1]->neighbors.push_back(wvertex);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But, it gives an error at compile time saying:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘graph_nodes[v1]->main()::node::neighbors’, which is of non-class type ‘std::pair<int, float>*’
```

I can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: There is no vector in your code.

Comment: You mean to use `std::vector< std::pair<int, float> >`?

Answer (score 2):

Change your struct definition to the following:

```
struct node{
    vector< pair<int, float> > neighbors;
};
```

This will allow you to add pairs to the vector neighbors. Note that pairs will be copied by value into the vector, which is what I assume you are trying to do anyways with the wvertex local variable.